# ScrollView and Admob Ad at the bottom

Tags: android, scrollview, admob

This is the screenshot of my application

[image]

Here is the xml for the screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90px"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewPrevious"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:height="25px"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="16px" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtxtInput"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="24px" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMain"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45px"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2px"
                android:background="#000000" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnVoiceCommand"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.60"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom_vc"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnClear"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="C"
                    android:textColor="#FF0000"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="DEL"
                    android:textColor="#FF0000"
                    android:textSize="24px" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45px"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2px"
                android:background="#000000" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnPower"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="^"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnFactors"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="F"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnPrime"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="P"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnMultiple"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="M"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSpace"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="____"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45px"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2px"
                android:background="#000000" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnInverse"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="1/x"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnFactorial"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="n!"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnPercentage"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="%"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNumberLeftBrace"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="("
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNumberRightBrace"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text=")"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45px"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2px"
                android:background="#000000" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnCubeRoot"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="³ √x"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNumber7"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="7"
                    android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNumber8"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="8"
                    android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNumber9"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="9"
                    android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNumberDivide"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="/"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45px"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2px"
                android:background="#000000" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSquareRoot"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="√x"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNumber4"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNumber5"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNumber6"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="6"
                    android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNumberMultiply"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="x"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45px"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2px"
                android:background="#000000" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSquare"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="x²"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNumber1"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNumber2"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNumber3"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNumberMinus"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45px"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2px"
                android:background="#000000" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnCube"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="x³"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNumberDot"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="."
                    android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNumber0"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNumberEqual"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="="
                    android:textColor="#00FF00"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNumberPlus"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="+"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

I want to place the AdMob Ad, at the bottom of this screen. When a user scrolls down, the advertisement should be visible. I don't want to keep the ad at the top, because, it will spoil the user experience. I could have used Relative layout, but then the user will have to scroll in order to tap the buttons in the calculator and that's not a good move.

Conditions :::
1. Ad only at the bottom.
2. No relative layout.

When i tried to place the ad in the scrollview, I got the output saying, "Required viewWidth 350, got 0". This could be because the of the usage of scrollview. Do I have a work around, where in the ads get displayed at the bottom, without shrinking the screen or the buttons..

Here is the code I want to add at the bottom of the screen..

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewAdvertisement"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30px"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="ADVERTISEMENT"
    android:textSize="24px" />

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="a1510b619xxxxx"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

Can I achieve what I want, through coding, if not from XML?

Thanks !!!

Update

[image]

The Advertisement is blocking the keys, and to access the bottom keys, I have to scroll down.

And also here is the logcat. The ad doesn't get displayed.

```
02-01 14:00:12.964: I/Ads(28406): Request scenario: Online server request.
02-01 14:00:14.924: W/webcore(28406): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
02-01 14:00:16.794: I/webview(28406): skipInvalidates
02-01 14:00:16.794: I/webview(28406): skipInvalidates
02-01 14:00:16.794: I/webview(28406): skipInvalidates
02-01 14:00:16.794: I/Ads(28406): onReceiveAd()
02-01 14:00:16.934: W/Ads(28406): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <320, 50>, Has: <0, 428>
```

Comment: When is a user going to try and scroll down a bunch of buttons of a calculator...?

Comment: i didn't get you. Do you mean, if i use a relative layout?

Comment: I mean in general, thinking about the design / use of this set-up. You're looking to create a screen (the calculator) which fills up with buttons. Then under the buttons, so out of sight at first, you want to place your advertisement. When is a user ever going to come up with the idea that he can scroll up the buttons...

Comment: Yeah, true. It doesn't make much sense though. But I can't compromise the user experience for the ad. I may have to look at interstitials, but they are not available to all. Do they?

Comment: So perhaps you're better off only adding the advertisement in bigger screens, where it can actually fit without making the buttons to small ;) I doubt you'll get payment from admob for ads that aren't actually visible anyway.. not sure if they check that

Comment: True. Just wanted to give it a try, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Make a few modifications to your XML as demonstrated in the code below. Notice the `android:layout_weight="1"` attribute used on the ScrollView.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90px"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    ....
    ....
    ....
</LinearLayout>


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        ....
        ....
        ....
        ....
    <LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom|center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewAdvertisement"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30px"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ADVERTISEMENT"
        android:textSize="24px" />

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="a1510b619xxxxx"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, YOUR_DEVICE_ID" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

Ideally, this should do it for you. Otherwise, I am stumped. Works just fine for me. The problem could also be because of using **px** values. But I am speculating on that since I have never used **px** values and don't know how they behave in such situations.

Comment: @VamsiChalla: Is the update after making the modifications I suggested?

Comment: Did you change any of the xml above? May be you are right, the use of px could be the problem. I am using the 0dip for width. Can I use the same to the height as well? I mean using 0dip for both height and weight at the same time, is it possible?

Comment: @VamsiChalla: I did change the code in the post. I am not sure if _0dip_ for both height and width can be used together. But do give it a try and see how they behave.

Comment: @VamsiChalla: Well, good luck and hopefully you will find a suitable alternative. :-)